# Using multiple routes and not enabled to use auth middleware

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have multiple route files in my laravel 5 project. Each of this files needs to use the Authentication Middleware. But when I try to request a route with a user that is not logged in from these files I'm getting this error:

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

This is one of the route files:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {

    Route::auth();

    Route::get('/marketplace/', '\App\Http\Controllers\Marketplaces\Controller@index');


});
```

And this is the RouteServiceProvider.php file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Routing\Router;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * This namespace is applied to the controller routes in your routes file.
     *
     * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

    protected $marketplaceNamespace = 'App\Http\Controllers\Marketplaces\';

    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Router  $router
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(Router $router)
    {
        //

        parent::boot($router);
    }

    /**
     * Define the routes for the application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Router  $router
     * @return void
     */
    public function map(Router $router)
    {

        $router->group(['namespace' => $this->namespace], function ($router) {
            require app_path('Http/Routes/routes.php');
        });

        $router->group(['namespace' => $this->marketplaceNamespace], function ($router) {
            require app_path('Http/Routes/routes.marketplace.php');
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the URL and HTTP method that results in such error?

Comment: the URL is http://localhost:8000/marketplace/ and the HTTP method is GET